# Oracle: Find null columns of a subset of a table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

In an Oracle database, is there a way to return all null columns of a subset of a table?

Similar to

```sql
select
        t.column_name
from 
        user_tab_columns t
where   t.nullable = 'Y'
and     t.table_name = 'MY_TABLE'
and     t.num_nulls = (select count(*) from MY_TABLE);
```

Except that instead of the entire table MY_TABLE I only want to select a subset of it.

Example:
If MY_TABLE looks like

```
A      B      C  
null | 1    | x  
null | null | y  
null | null | y
```

I would want the query to return 'A' and 'B' if my where clause is where C = 'y'.

Comment: Can you provide sample data to illustrate what you mean?

Comment: @GordonLinoff added an example, hope that clears it up a bit. I want the query to return the names of the columns of MY_TABLE where in a chosen subset those columns consist only of null values.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all `null` columns you can use an outer join:

```
select t.*
from (select 1 as n from dual) x left join
     my_table t
     on 1 = 0;
```